# What is the proper name for -webkit- / -moz- prefixes in CSS?

Tags: css

I have used -webkit- and -moz- prefixes for a long time now and I don't know what the proper name for these prefixes is. Could someone please put my mind at ease and tell me what the proper name is?

Comment: vendor prefix or browser prefix -- http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments "vendor prefix" and "browser prefix" are the most commonly used names.

[It looks like the w3c refers to them as "Vendor-specific extensions"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#vendor-keywords), but that is the only place I've ever seen them called that.

I usually say "browser prefix", no one has ever corrected me or not understood what I meant when saying it.